# Trying to center a Wufoo form in an iframe using CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, iframe

I'm using Wufoo for a web form.  The form is in my page in an iframe.  They let you use custom CSS to style the form.  I'm trying to center the form in the iframe.

Here's the HTML I grabbed from the page when the form is displayed in the iframe:

```
<div id="container" class="ltr">
    <form id="form2" name="form2" class="wufoo topLabel page1 hideHeader" accept-charset="UTF-8" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" novalidate="true" action="https://peakinbound.wufoo.com/embed/mtco4fp0qomvz2/def/&amp;header=hide#public">
        <ul>
            <li id="fo2li1" class="notranslate">
                <label class="desc" id="title1" for="Field1">
                    Name<span id="req_1" class="req">*</span>
                </label> 
                <span> 
                    <input id="Field1" name="Field1" type="text" class="field text fn" value="" size="8" tabindex="1" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required="true" />
                    <label for="Field1">First</label>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <input id="Field2" name="Field2" type="text" class="field text ln" value="" size="14" tabindex="2" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required="true" />
                    <label for="Field2">Last</label>
                </span>
            </li>
            <li id="fo2li3" class="notranslate">
                <label class="desc" id="title3" for="Field3">
                    Email<span id="req_3" class="req">*</span>
                </label>
                <div>
                    <input id="Field3" name="Field3" type="email" spellcheck="false" class="field text medium" value="" maxlength="255" tabindex="3" onkeyup="handleInput(this);" onchange="handleInput(this);" required="true" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="buttons ">
                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="currentPage" id="currentPage" value="jssDPjBF2iK6t1UvInla0mSUbe82kYF5HwuBetLwuBe5y49jw=" />
                    <input id="saveForm" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" type="submit" value="GET INFO" onmousedown="doSubmitEvents();" />
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<!--container-->
```

I tried using this on the CSS but it didn't center the form.

```
#container {
    width: 350;
    height: 250; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this form centered?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you provide some images ?

Comment: Added the "px" to the width and height. Form still not centered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a measuring unit in px.
http://jsfiddle.net/73TSr/10/
http://jsfiddle.net/73TSr/10/show

```
#iframe-container {
    width: 350px;
    height: 300px; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
#iframe-container > iframe {
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Did that.  Still not centered.

Comment: It should work unless you have another style overriding it. My example works derived from your code example.

Comment: But you have it with an iframe. Is the iframe inside the #container or the other way around?

Comment: The container is in the iframe.Hmm.  It's Wufoo so maybe there's stuff I'm not seeing on their side.

Comment: You need a container wrapping the iframe to be able to center it. See the updated answer.

Comment: @user3453424: If there is any absolute positioning on container, you also need to set right/left to 0. Easiest way to check (if out of control) is *Inspect element* or the like from context menu in various browsers like Chrome and Fire Fox.